# How to align list item of Asp radio button element?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

The gap between radio buttons has fixed width and text is going downside. `asp:ListItem` does not allow `div` or `label` element. I want to set the width of `asp:ListItem` according to the text. I can edit the width using `inspect source` but I do not know how to give width to each list item in Visual studio.  I am beginner to C# Could somebody help me how can I do this?

```html
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                 OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem >Add</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Clear all lines of code</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Do nothing</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

[image]

Comment: `<asp:ListItem class="whatever">` then in a CSS file `.whatever { width: 100px }` and change 100px to whatever value works for you. If you don't know CSS, please search online.

Comment: <asp:ListItem> does not allow "class" attribute. I cannot use any css class inside `<asp:ListItem>`

Comment: Sorry, Use `CssClass` instead of `class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (notice the addition of the "CssClass" to your RadioButtonList [not the ListItem]):

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" CssClass="myRadioList" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
             OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
               <asp:ListItem >Add</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Clear all lines of code</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Do nothing</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Then in CSS:

```
.myRadioList input[type="radio"] { width: auto; }
.myRadioList label { font-weight:bold; width: auto; }
```

I don't believe that ASP.NET uses fixed widths for radio button lists typically.  I'm thinking that you have some style set somewhere that is forcing the width.  Perhaps a global "label" or "input" style.

Without knowing what your other CSS looks like, it's impossible to say for sure if this will fix it.  For example, if you have a min-width set or something, I believe that'll still be enforced.  You could try adding `min-width:0` and the dreaded `!important` rule (this is considered bad practice though) to try to force it to be the all-powerful ruler of all.

Comment: thank you so much. yes there was global style for label which I didn't notice.